# Every subring of integers is of the form $m\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $S$ be a subring of $\mathbb Z$. Prove that $S=m\mathbb Z$ for some $m\in \mathbb N_0$.

I really have no clue. But if $S$ is a subring that means $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb Z$ and it contains a $0$ and is closed under addition, scalar multiplication and for all $A$ in $S$, $-A$ is in $S$.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Already answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477303/subrings-of-mathbbzi?rq=1). See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540787/proof-that-bbb-z-has-no-other-subring-than-itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the smallest positive difference $d$ between any two elements $a$ and $b$ in the subring. Why must all multiples of $d$ be in the subring? Can there be any elements of the subring other than multiples of $d$?

Comment: All multiples of d must be in the subring because the difference of any two integers is an integer itself so its in S. And no there can't? I still have no clue

Comment: Suppose there is an element $e$ in the subring such that $e$ is not a multiple of $d$. Can you find a contradiction based on the definition of $d$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ be the minimal positive integer in $S$. Then $n$ divides all the other elements of $S$. This is true, because if you find $x$ an element in $S$ not divided by $n$ then $x = np + r$, where $0 < r < n$. Since $x, np \in S$, then $r = x - np \in S$. But this is contradiction, because we chose $n$ to be the minimal positive in $S$. So $S = (n)$, which is not only subring of Z, but also an ideal.

Comment: What do you mean by ideal? And S=(n)?

Comment: Oh (n) is another notation for nZ. Ideal is a subset of a ring, which is closed under substration and multiplication with elements of the whole ring. Every ideal is a subring too.

Comment: Could you explain more on how its a contradiction please. I understood everything until that part.

Comment: Well I supposed that there is an element in S that is not divisible by n and found it's reminder r, which is smaller that n and in S too, but there is no positive element of S smaller than n, because n is minimal. This is the contradiction.

Comment: Don't you have to consider the case is S={0}? Amd then when S is not equal to {0}?

Comment: @snowman Ah, $\{0\}$ is subring of every single ring in the world. Yeah, this is kind of special case.

Comment: When u say let n be the minimal positive integer, does that include zero? Im guessing not but dont u have to make it include zero aswell because in the question it has m as an element as N_0

Comment: @snowman no I have considered that the subring is not trivial ({0}). This works when it contains not-zero elements. However if you want to be super formal you can split the proof in these 2 cases.

Comment: @snowman note that if the subring has an element $x \neq 0$ then $x$ and $-x$ are in the subring and therefore it has at least $1$ positive element

Comment: OK so if the 2 cases are if S={0} and if S is not equal to {0}, then is your answer the second case only?

Comment: @snowman exactly

Comment: That's the thing, I understand this second case but I do not understand the first case. how do you prove that S=mZ if S={0}? if that's the case then since we S=mZ={mx:x is integer} and m is N_0, this either means that x is zero or m is zero right? I don't get it at all.

Comment: @snowman if $S = \{0\}$ then obviously $S = 0\mathbb{Z}$ noting so difficult :)

Comment: wait, that's all you gotta say for the first case? because Im trying to write a super formal proof

Comment: @snowman Well the most most formal way I can think of is to show that $\{0\} = 0\mathbb{Z}$. And this is done like this: suppose $x \in \{0\} \Rightarrow x = 0 \Rightarrow x = 0*0 \in 0\mathbb{Z}$. And the converse if $x \in 0\mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow x = 0*a = 0$ $(a \in 0\mathbb{Z})$, then $x = 0 \in \{0\}$.

Comment: Hi, you know the answer u posted, doesnt that just prove that S is a subset of mZ? What would u do to show that mZ is a subset of S?

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint :}$ If $S$ is a subring then it is a subgroup also. Next subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic. Can you conclude now?