# Yes/no: Do odd integers form a subring of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Do odd integers form a subring of $\mathbb{Z}$?

My attempt: Yes, from this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992312/every-subring-of-integers-is-of-the-form-m-mathbb-z)

My logic is that  if $n$ is any integer (odd/even)  the set of all multiples of $n$ is a subring $n\mathbb{Z}$ of $\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: It's not closed under addition.

Comment: $3+3 \in \mathbb{Z}$@lulu i think it closed

Comment: $3+3=6$ is not odd.

Comment: Your set $S$ consists of the odd integers only.  $1\in S$ for example.  But $1+1\notin S$.  For that matter, $0\notin S$ so there isn't even an additive identity.

Comment: What you call a subring is actually  an ideal.

Comment: @Bernard that was my misunderstanding ,actually before posting this question   i was thinking that $3+3 \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Why, yes $6$ is in $\mathbf Z$, but, more precisely, it's in $2\mathbf Z$.

Comment: ya got it@Bernard  **Even** integer form a subring of $\mathbb{Z}$  but  not odd integer

Comment: @lulu  i.e. being not closed under subtraction they fail the [subgroup test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test), hence fail the [subring test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the following statement is true:

> if $n$ is any integer, then the set of all multiples of $n$ is a subring of $\mathbb Z$.

However, you have the set $A$ of all **odd** integers. For which integer $n$ does the set $A$ equal the set of all multiples of $n$? If you cannot find such a value $n$, then the statement outlined above cannot be used to prove that $A$ is a subring.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Any odd number plus an odd number is an even number.

Comment: i.e. being not closed under subtraction they fail the [subgroup test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test), so fail the [subring test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test).